# How do I reset the value of the textfield based on what chosen on the radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have these radio buttons for male and female. If the user has clicked 'male ', a text field will appear for the message. The problem is if I'll choose `male` and then type in the message and I'll choose `female` the next time, the value of the textfield `msg` is still there. How can I change it back to just nothing?

The message is still there even if I have already clicked 'male'

[image]

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-button-cn9708?file=/demo.js

codes:

```
export default function ControlledRadioButtonsGroup() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const [msg, setMsg] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl>
        <FormLabel id="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group">Gender</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-labelledby="demo-controlled-radio-buttons-group"
          name="controlled-radio-buttons-group"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
          <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
      {value === "male" && (
        <TextField
          label="msg"
          value={msg}
          onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}
        />
      )}
      {msg} - Message
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried this:

```
  if (value === "female") {
    setMsg("");
  }
```

But this will show as:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an
> infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that in the `handleChange` handler:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === "female") {
      setMsg("");
    }
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap this part into `useEffect` hook

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value === "female") {
      setMsg("");
    }
  }, [value])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => { value === 'female' && setMsg('') }, [value])
```

The array in the second parameter (`[value]`) specifies the dependencies. If any of the  dependencies change, the effect will be triggered. Just remember that it only does a shallow comparison.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value === "female") {
      setMsg("");
    }
  }, [value]);
```

[image: Edit Radio button (forked)]